# Count number of columns having zeros

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame-

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,0],[4,5,0],[7,8,0]])
```

I want to calculate the number of columns which have all the rows as zero in it. In the above case, the 3rd column has all zeros so the output would be 1

Comment: ``df.eq(0).all().sum()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.sum` and then `series.sum`:

```
df.sum().eq(0).sum()
#1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative.

```
df.astype(bool).sum(axis=0).isin([0]).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

this would easy and compact solution try it

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([[0,2,0],[0,5,0],[0,8,0]])
    df=(df.sum())
    answer=(df==0).sum()
```